# Should I use iframes to load external html?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm creating a website where there are four sections but only a main page, with a navbar which allows me to switch from one to another section with a pretty cool carousel effect. The HTML code of each section is elsewhere, and I'm using four iframes to load it at the moment. Should I keep using iframes or should I switch to something like ajax and divs? 
PS. I'm encountering some problems with the height of the iframesat the moment, so I would be glad if you tell me to switch to divs :D
EDIT: the code is elsewhere but under my control

Comment: Thing with divs, they don't load the html page like iFrame. For example the javascript loaded in that iFrame won't work in div. I think this is a case where you should go with iFrames. Regarding iFrame heights. You cannot access the html of your iFrames since (I am assuming) cross-domain security.

Comment: What does *"The HTML code of each section is elsewhere"* mean specifically? is it code you control?

Comment: Yes, I control it. I mean, it is not in the same file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a templating system for this instead of iframes. The use of iframes could become troublesome for you going forwards because it would be a little messier to manipulate the DOM freely between those four sections (and potentially not possible dependent on where your content is loaded from), if you ever decide to do that. You'd need to access each iframes document and go from there.

A good example of a templating system is [Handlebars JS](http://handlebarsjs.com/). This will let you throw chunks of HTML into their own files and call on them to append/insert into the DOM where you please with little function calls.

Comment: Assumes OP controls source of iframes which isn't clear in question

Comment: @charlietfl thanks you are right I misread that. Will see what he replies to your comment and edit or delete this based on that.

Comment: Yes, it is under my control. Thanks